# change icon of page action - Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, favicon

I have four `.png` images in my images folder:

1. Default icon      256x256 (manifest:page_action:default_icon)
2. Replacement icon: 128x128
3. Test icon1:       12x12
4. Test icon2:       256x256

I use the first icon by default. This works.
Replacing it with the second one, works too.
The third the same.

The fourth will not be picked up, therefore chrome picks the default one.
This must be a bug, otherwise I cannot explain it.
Because the fourth one, has the same format, size as the default icon...!?

But perhaps you guys know better, why the fourth png won't be applied as an page_action icon?

[Chrome icons](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/icons)

> Icons should generally be in PNG format, because PNG has the best
>   support for transparency. They can, however, be in any format
>   supported by WebKit, including BMP, GIF, ICO, and JPEG. Here's an
>   example of specifying the icons:
>
> "icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
>              "48": "icon48.png",
>             "128": "icon128.png" }, **You may provide icons of any other size you wish**, and Chrome will attempt to use the best size where
>   appropriate. For example, Windows often requires 32-pixel icons, and
>   if the app includes a 32-pixel icon, Chrome will choose that instead
>   of shrinking a 48-pixel icon down. However, you should ensure that all
>   of your icons are square, or unexpected behavior may result.

Comment: The question is unanswerable. Provide a MCVE.

Comment: I have created a reproduceable example, but I use images there which I don't have a license for. Do you think it's a problem if I upload the code into Github?